# Implementing a complex method to compare two sets of Strings when groups of one are associated with a third

Tags: java, string, dictionary, wildcard

I have a rather complex method that I need to implement. So please bear with me as I try to describe it in as simple a way as I can.

I'm given a set A of Strings that represent filenames - let's say "abc", "def", and "ghi". I must derive from these names a set B of "associated" filenames for each - let's say "abc_123", "abc_456", and "abc_789" for "abc"; "def_123", "def_456", and "def_789" for "def"; and "ghi_123", "ghi_456", and "ghi_789" for "ghi". This much I can do. However, these associated filenames may have prefixes or suffixes attached to them which are unpredictable strings of characters - so the associated filenames for "abc" might actually be "HELLOabc_123WORLD", "FOOabc_456BAR", and "999abc_789000". (In terms of regular expressions, it's just a matter of putting a * on both sides of the associated filenames I had written above). In short, the associated filenames will look like this:

```
*<original filename><other piece that I know>*
```

where the stars indicate any number of random characters (could be 0).

That's the first piece of the puzzle.

Next, I am given another set C of Strings that I am to compare to the set of associated filenames (set B). (In case you're wondering, I'm trying to check if the associated files are in a certain directory, and I have the list of filenames in that directory, set C). If I find all the associated filenames for a certain file in set C, I can go ahead and check off that file from set A. I must go and check each filename in set A, and if all of its associated filenames from set B are found in set C, I can check off that file from set A.

Finally, I must return the filenames from set A that were not checked off (so I'd return nothing if everything was found).

I've been struggling to come up with a way to implement this method. I thought of creating a Map that would map a filename from set A to a List containing all the filenames associated with that filename like so:

```
Key        Value
abc        *abc_123*, *abc_456*, *abc_789*
def        *def_123*, *def_456*, *def_789*
ghi        *ghi_123*, *ghi_456*, *ghi_789*
```

I could then traverse the elements of this map, and the values of the elements, comparing them to the Strings in set C. And if all Elements of the value (the List) for a given Key are found in set C, I could mark that Key off my list. Any Keys remaining would be returned.

This seems to me like it should work, but the actual mechanics of putting that into code have been very challenging for me. So if you could give me any small suggestions or pointers that would move my thinking in the right direction, I'd appreciate it very much. My implementation language will be Java in case you'd like to give code. Pseudocode is welcomed as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have correctly identified the solution partially to your problem. You will need a Map for sure and essentially your problem boils down to finding if all elements in a given list are present in a set of strings in C. I am not sure about what data structure is holding the set B or C of strings. But I can provide a pseudo code for the rest:

```
Initialize a HashMap<String, ArrayList>
for each string in set B
  if it matches the pattern *abc_*
     if "abc" is already in the Map
        get the value of this key in a temp list and append this string at the end of the list
     else
        add a new entry into the Map

   //follow the same for the other patterns.

for each entry in the Map
  traverse the list of values
    check if this value is present in the set C 
      if you reach the end of the list,
        remove the entry from the Map
```

That way, you are left with only the keys in the Map, that you need to return.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure if I understand your problem correctly, but this is how I imagine it:

```
List<String> setCStrings = //your set C strings I guess...
for(String aSetCString : setCStrings) {
    String pattern = ".*" + filename + "_" + associatedFileName + ".*";
    if(aSetCString.matches(pattern)) {
        // do what you want with this string that matches the filename and associated file name
    }
}
```